# Segmentation fault on macOS but not on Ubuntu

Tags: c, macos, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to free a linked list in my code. When I try to free the node and print that address it gives a segmentation fault. But if I try it on Ubuntu, it works correctly. My code is like that:

```
void Free(struct node* head) {
    while(head !=NULL){
        free(head);
        head=head->next;
   }
}
```

My struct is :

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
```

Why is it not working on macOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't dereference a pointer after you've freed it. You need to save `head->next` before you free `head`.

```
void Free(struct node* head) {
    while(head !=NULL){
        node *next = head->next;
        free(head);
        head=next;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I tried it but its not working too. Also I was wondering how can it works in ubuntu? Whats the difference?

Comment: If you're still having problems, they're because of other bugs in your code. Are you sure the last node has `next == NULL`?

Comment: Yes it has. Should i write next->next=NULL?

Comment: No, you don't need that since you're freeing them.

Comment: I think I have a problem with printing it. After the delete operation, if I don't write the list again, it works. But when I try to write it, I got segmentation fault.

Comment: You can't use nodes that have been freed. Why are you trying to print after you delete?

Comment: struct node* create_sample_list(void) {
    struct node* head = NULL;
    struct node* second = NULL;
    struct node* third = NULL;

    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->data = 10;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 20;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 30;
    third->next = NULL;

    return head;
}.    Thats my code which creates nodes

Comment: Print the list before you free it.

Comment: Because I was wondering its deleted or not. When I try it on ubuntu it me gives the random numbers. But in macOS its not working. Is that normal that I can't print that?

Comment: Yes, it's normal. Undefined behavior means anything can happen -- it can produce an error, or it might appear to work.

Comment: Okey sir thanks for your answers and im sorry for this stupid question :)